# Use of pci_iomap() and ioremap_nocache() functions in UART(8250) driver

Tags: serial-port, driver, linux-device-driver, uart, pci

- I'm understanding driver code for UART- **8250.c** and **8250_pci.c** from Linux.
- I've problem in understanding use of **pci_iomap** and **ioremap_nocache** function call.

  1) Means why they are used in code?

  2) And what is significance of  Address return by both functions?

Need help.Thanks.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/deviceiobook/API-ioremap-nocache.html

Comment: @Ansh..i read this link.But i could not come to exact conclusion that why ioremap_nocache is used after pci_iomap?

Answer (score 4):

The way to access I/O memory depends on the computer architecture, bus, and device being used, although the principles are the same everywhere. Depending on the computer platform and bus being used, I/O memory may or may not be accessed through page tables. When access passes though page tables, the kernel must first arrange for the physical address to be visible from your driver, and this usually means that you must call ioremap before doing any I/O. If no page tables are needed, I/O memory locations look pretty much like I/O ports, and you can just read and write to them using proper wrapper functions.

Allocation of I/O memory is not the only required step before that memory may be accessed. You must also ensure that this I/O memory has been made accessible to the kernel. Getting at I/O memory is not just a matter of dereferencing a pointer; on many systems, I/O memory is not directly accessible in this way at all. So a mapping must be set up first. This is the role of the ioremap function. Once equipped with ioremap (and iounmap), a device driver can access any I/O memory address, whether or not it is directly mapped to virtual address space. Remember, though, that the addresses returned from ioremap should not be dereferenced directly; instead, accessor functions provided by the kernel should be used.

ioremap_nocache: Quoting from one of the kernel headers: "It's useful if some control registers are in such an area, and write combining or read caching is not desirable"

Few of the accessor functions are, to read from I/O memory

```
unsigned int ioread8(void *addr);
unsigned int ioread16(void *addr);
unsigned int ioread32(void *addr);
```

Here, addr should be an address obtained from ioremap (perhaps with an integer offset); the return value is what was read from the given I/O memory.

There is a similar set of functions for writing to I/O memory:

```
void iowrite8(u8 value, void *addr);
void iowrite16(u16 value, void *addr);
void iowrite32(u32 value, void *addr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`pci_iomap()` maps PCI resources as such as IORESOURCE_MEM and IORESOURCE_IO (legacy). `ioremap()` makes the physical IO address space usable for IO accessors. `ioremap()` works for any devices regardless to which bus it's attached and enumerated.

To answer for your question. The `ioremap_nochache()` is used only in **two** places in the driver. And each of them is custom to some hardware. I suspect this happened due to chronological changes since 8250 is one of the oldest drivers in the kernel.

Comment: @Andy..Means returns address of  `pci_iomap()` is address from where driver can access data same as directly from configuration space in pci card.is it right?

Comment: Look at the prototypes. `pci_iomap()` maps the regions but does not return anything.

Comment: @Andy..yes.its return type is void.But it gives `__iomem` address to device BAR..If that address used in `ioread16(address return from pci_iomap())` (without offset)function, then it gives Class and revision id. [pci_iomap explain](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/deviceiobook/API-pci-iomap.html). So is `pci_iomap()` function maps memory from address which shows class and rev id?

Comment: `pci_iomap()` maps the resources (it might be not memory address, but IO) from PCI BARs.

Comment: @Andy..Is there any method that we can check that  `ioremap` retuns value is correct or not?

Comment: It will return NULL on x86 for example, on other architectures could be different story, though I guess that the return value meaning is the same.